# One controller uses its corresponding layout, but the other does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

My Rails project has two controllers, a SessionsController and a CustomersController. My project also has two layout views in the layouts directory, sessions.html.erb and customers.html.erb.

I would like the SessionsController to render using the session.html.erb layout and the CustomersController to render using the customers.html.erb layout.

I have removed all explicit layout commands from my project, so as far as I understand it the required functionality should now occur.

However, what is actually happening is that the CustomersController is using customers.html.erb layout as expected but the SessionsController is using no layout at all. (I removed the default application.html.erb layout entirely, so it has nothing to fall back on.)

I have ALSO tried explicitly setting the layouts in each controller with layout: ".html.erb", but the behaviour was the same.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def initialize
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader   :errors

  def read_attribute_for_validation(attr)
    send(attr)
  end

  def SessionsController.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {} )
    attr
  end

  def SessionsController.lookup_ancestors
    [self]
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    customer = Customer.find_by(customerID: params[:session][:user_id])
    if customer && customer.correct_password?(params[:session][:password])
      log_in customer
      remember customer
      customer.update_last_action_time
      redirect_to customer
    else
      @errors.add(:base, "UserID cannot be blank") if params[:session][:user_id].blank?
      @errors.add(:base, "Password cannot be blank") if params[:session][:password].blank?
      # Only push this final messag if there were no other errors
      @errors.add(:base, "Unrecognised UserID / password combination") if @errors.count == 0
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

CustomersController:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_customer
  before_action :correct_customer

  def seo
#    @customer = Customer.find_by(params[:customerID])
  end

  def show
#    @customer = Customer.find_by(params[:customerID])
  end

  def edit
#   @customer = Customer.find_by(params[:customerID])
  end

  def update
#   @customer = Customer.find_by(params[:customerID])
    if @customer.update(customer_params)
      render "edit"
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit( :new_email,
                                      :new_password,
                                      :new_password_confirmation,
                                      :existing_password,
                                      :update_type )
  end

  def logged_in_customer
    if logged_in? && !timed_out?
      # Intentionally blank
    else
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  def correct_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(customer_path(current_customer)) unless current_customer?(@customer)
  end

end
```

sessions.html.erb:

```
<%= render "shared/intro" %>

  <div class="header">
    <%= image_tag "rebrand.png", alt: "株式会社リブランド" %>
  </div>

  <div class="main-panel">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    SEO-care
  </div>

<%= render "shared/outro" %>
```

customers.html.erb:

```
<%= render "shared/intro" %>

<%= render "shared/header" %>

<%= render "shared/left_panel" %>

<%= render "shared/top_panel" %>

  <!-- add any always-used formatting here -->
  <div class="main-panel">

    <%= yield %>

  <!-- add any always-used formatting here -->
  </div>
</div>

<%= render "shared/footer" %>

<%= render "shared/outro" %>
```

I have not included the content of the partials, but think I can rule them out as the application seems to not even find the layout file, let alone get around to considering the contents of its partials. This can be seen in the console output when rendering a page from each controller:

Sessions:

```
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb (12.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 20.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Customers:

```
  Rendered customers/show.html.erb within layouts/customers (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_intro.html.erb (183.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_left_panel.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_top_panel.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_outro.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 249ms (Views: 203.2ms | ActiveRecord: 39.4ms)
```

Comment: Make sure the layout is called `sessions.html.erb` and not singular (`session`) as you mentioned in the post.

Comment: Alas, it is "sessions.html.erb". :( The typo was just in the question, I am afraid. Although I am sure the problem is an equally monumentally stupid typo, somewhere...

Comment: How did you specified which layout to use in controller ?

Comment: Have you tried using `layout 'sessions'`? Other than that you have a lot of unidiomatic and just plain weird stuff going on in your `SessionsController`. Extending `ActiveModel::Naming` sounds like it could cause some conflict as it may interfere with the way Rails tries to inflect resources based on the controller name. Also use `def self.some_method` or `class << self` to declare class methods https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide.  You also should be binding errors to the Customer instance instead of creating a Errors object in the controller (skinny controllers are the shiz).

Comment: I had tried explicitly setting layout using layout "sessions". I just tried again now too. The result is still the same. Also, I now notice that the console makes no reference to looking for / failing to find the sessions.html.erb layout. I commented out extend ActiveModel::Naming but the behaviour was unaffected. The SessionsController is based on https://www.railstutorial.org but with a few changes; the problem with adding errors to customer is there might not be a customer object (this is pre-login) and the customer object not being passed back to the page if we reload upon a failed login.

Comment: I guess I could create an empty customer object and then update that upon successful login. Thanks for the style guide; at this stage I am still at the stage of "get it working" but I would like to adopt a style guide once I am a little more comfortable with RoR. Whilst I am trying to adopt Ruby conventions I do sometimes find verbose code useful when trying to debug problems. (I could do a little more refactoring though!) Bonus points for @maxcal as that style guide has a Japanese translation for my colleagues! :D

Comment: Right, I can see now the problem is the initialize method; it must be overriding some behaviour in one of SessionController's base ("super"?) classes. Solution for now seems to be adding a call to super. Will confirm everything works then add as an answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution:

The `initialize` method appears to be overriding one in a base class. A quick solution is to ensure the base `initialize` method is also called using `super`:

```
def initialize
  super
  @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
end
```

Potentially better solution:

Extending ActiveModel::Naming to expose the error message functionality may not be the best way of handling errors in this case; finding a way to add the errors to a customer object and then using those errors (thus negating the need to extend ActiveModel::Naming at all) may be a preferred long-term solution. Thanks to @maxcal for this suggestion.